# How to return from an async method?

Tags: dart, flutter

Based on the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-example-tab-) class, I try to retrieve a preference value like so:

```
String loadIPAddress() {

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences prefs) {

      try {

        var loadedValue = prefs.getString('serverIPAddress');
        print('loadIPAddress <= ' + loadedValue);
        return loadedValue; // [1]

      } catch (e) {

        print('loadIPAddress <= NOPE');
        return '---'; [2]

      }
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't return a value each time.

**Q: Does the [1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-example-tab-) and [2] return statements return the value of loadIPAddress()?**

Comment: Might be easier to work with SharedPreferences if you use this package:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pref_dessert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you've guessed, those returns return from the `then` callback.

To return from `loadIPAddress`, refactor it like this:

```
Future<String> loadIPAddress() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  try {
    var loadedValue = prefs.getString('serverIPAddress');
    print('loadIPAddress <= ' + loadedValue);
    return loadedValue;
  } catch (e) {
    print('loadIPAddress <= NOPE');
    return '---';
  }
}
```

Note that having made `loadIPAddress` async, it now returns a Future, so you should call it like:

```
String ip = await loadIPAddress();
// or
loadIPAddress().then((String ip) {
  // do something with ip - probably setState
});
```